# How do I look up the folder where a portlet was defined?

Tags: plone, portlet

I'm creating custom versions of the News and Events portlets which will show only content items from downstream of where they are defined (rather than sitewide).

The idea is for for certain groups in our site to be able to create news and events portlets that only show the items from their downstream folder hierarchy.

Essentially, I swapped out

`portal_state.navigation_root_path()`

for

`path='/'.join(context.getPhysicalPath())`

in the view's catalog query

The problem I'm running into, is that context.getPhysicalPath() is evaluated based on where the portlet is being viewed, not the the location where the portlet was defined.  Once someone navigates downstream from the top-level group folder, they often end up with an empty or disappearing portlet.

How do I look up the folder on which the portlet is defined so that I can pass that as my context?

Comment: Here are some tips showing digging up the portlet assignment context: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/portlets/tips.html#checking-if-a-certain-context-portlet-is-active-on-a-page

Answer (score 4):

I think you want the `__portlet_metadata__['key']`:

```
(Pdb) self.context.restrictedTraverse(self.__portlet_metadata__['key'])
<ATFolder at /plone/Members/test_user_1_>
```